# Relation between norms on a vector space and norm on a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

A norm is a special type of metric defined on a vector space. It gives a vector space some topological structure and the hart of Functional Analysis.

First time in this morning I was seeing the term in Euclidean Domain, Ring Theory. It is a function $N : R \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, with $N(\theta) = 0$ where $\theta$ is the zero element of the ring $R$.

Is there any relation between two concepts? Please discuss.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Norm on a vector space is more a way of measuring length as there exist metrics that are not induced by a norm which you probably know already.As for the norm you are referring to its defined with the intention of framing a generalisation of Division algorithm in general for Division rings.They arent related much except for the fact that they satisfy same kinds of conditions,like positive definite and additive (multiplicative) inequalities. They are interesting when looked at as valuations to define Euclidean domains and so on.

Comment: @Vishesh Thank you for your comment. Write it please as an answer.

Comment: Thats alright.It will suffice if it helped you clear your doubt. No issues